# Why does my VB.NET Function shows a warning

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

```
  Public Function Delete_GST_Entry(ByVal GE_ID As Integer) As DataTable
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(DF_Class.GetConnectionString())
            Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable
            con.Open()
            Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Delete_GSTEntry", con)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("GE_ID", GE_ID)
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
            Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            Return ds 
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Input Error")

    End Try

End Function
```

I am getting a warning saying that a `NULL reference could occur`. What is the mistake I am doing?

Warning:

> "Function 'Delete_GST_Entry' doesn't return a value on all code paths.
>   A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is
>   used. "

Comment: Warning "Function 'Delete_GST_Entry' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used

Comment: You can add Return null as last statment. so all code return a value

Comment: @Deepak: you mean like I posted 30 minutes prior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All exit points (return paths) of a method must return what the method's signature specifies.

Re-write like this:

```
Public Function Delete_GST_Entry(ByVal GE_ID As Integer) As DataTable
   Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

   Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(DF_Class.GetConnectionString())
             con.Open()
            Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Delete_GSTEntry", con)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("GE_ID", GE_ID)
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
            adapter.Fill(dt)
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Input Error")
    End Try

    Return dt    ' Note will be empty if stored proc call fails...
End Function
```

Ideally, you should wrap the connection in a using statement.